# Different values for env vars based on the environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables

Currently, I have a `.env` file with development and production configuration, every time I have to comment out the development configuration in production and production configuration in development.How can I make it dynamic? I found the below resources,

[Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50610832/managing-configurations-for-different-environments/50611386#50611386)
[Reference 2](https://rednafi.github.io/digressions/python/2020/06/03/python-configs.html)

But I am unable to understand how I will access it.Currently I am importing the env variables in settings.py and assigning it to the variable as below

```
DB_NAME = os.getenv("db_name")
DB_PASS = os.getenv("db_password")
```

I am using fastapi as framework.

Comment: The first reference specifically says you tell it if its development or production. You set the environment variable `APP_SETTINGS` to be `"DevelopmentConfig"` or `"ProductionConfig"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.env` file should not be committed to source control. Normally you commit a file `.env.example`  where you list which variables are available. Then in each environment you create a `.env` file unique to that environment.

If you are deploying with `rsync` or similar tool, make sure you exclude the `.env` file so you don't overwrite it.